# showing record from table year wise

Tags: oracle, timestamp

```
select station_id,count(case_id) from emer_complaint group by station_id
```

Above query returning the correct result. But, when i'm trying this query for showing the record in year wise. Then it shows the error `ORA-00904: "YEAR": invalid identifier`

```
select year(date_time)
      ,count(case_id) 
 from emer_complaint  
group by year(date_time);
```

the datatype of `date_time` is `Timestamp`.

Thanks in advance.!!

Comment: You need [`to_char`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php). `Year()` is not an Oracle function.

Comment: thanks @Ben for your valuable help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select to_char(date_time, 'YYYY'), count(case_id)
from   emer_complaint
group by to_char(date_time, 'YYYY');
```

Comment: it works !! but, it return `1-JAN-2012`. So, i used `to_char` as Ben has suggested. Thanks for your help !!